# Setting up Scale Domain and Bar Width for multiple bar charts in one page

Tags: d3.js

I am very new to D3.  I have a large JSON array that I am pulling into D3 via AJAX to make bar graphs.  The array is used to generate multiple slides in a Bootstrap carousel, where each slide is an element of the array (i below) with corresponding sub elements.  I have run into issues setting up x and y scale's by extracting directly from this large array so I have put the necessary values in separate arrays (although this obviously has not solved the problem yet).

These arrays, which are the same length as the number of slides, are maxDefectCounts() and numberOfBars().  Note, they are not associative arrays/JSON, they are data that I have extracted from the JSON.

I would like the height of the largest bar in each slide to be equal to maxDefectCounts[i] where i is the current slide.  I would like the width of the bar to be numberOfBars[i] / width of SVG that the bar chart is bound to.

For the y-scale I have tried the following with no luck.  I'm not sure if you can bind a separate data element to a scale function (note that I am using j instead of I in the function below so as not to be confused with i, which is the slide number)

```
     var y = d3.scale.linear()
       .range([height,0])
       .data(maxDefectCounts)
       .enter()
       .domain([0,function(d,j){return d[j];}]);
```

For width what I am currently doing is iterating through the different bars in d.binSummary and using a fixed value of barWidth (this is for testing).  Since each slide has a different number of bars, I would like this to be proportional to numberOfBars[i] instead of this fixed value

```
var bar = paretoBox.selectAll("g")
    .data(function(d) {return d.binSummary;})
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",function(d,j) {
        return "translate(" + j * barWidth + ",0)";
    });
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified a workaround.  Since independent values are needed for each slide, I built a loop that takes the original JSON as an input and builds a slide for each element.  This allows the extraction of the needed information.  A similar approach is used [here](https://vida.io/documents/jjwqo6jzJTsZaCxBE) with regard to building multiple charts with a single input array.

Comment: Unfortunately it slows things down a bit.